# meteor-simple-schema vs meteor-astronomy

Tags: meteor, simple-schema, mantrajs

Can someone please give a comparison between [meteor-simple-schema](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema) and [meteor-astronomy](https://github.com/jagi/meteor-astronomy) (pros and cons as well please) and advise on which one is better to use with the Mantra architecture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The creator of Simple Schema has [said](https://forums.meteor.com/t/new-package-mdg-validated-method-meteor-methods-with-better-scoping-argument-checking-and-good-defaults/13833/19) that if Astronomy existed when he created Simple Schema, he would not have.

From practical experience, Astronomy is miles ahead of Simple Schema and I use it with all my projects. I don't know about the Mantra architecture but a casual review confirms Astronomy would work, and well.